# TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. Arcgis 4.13

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am using arcgis 4.13 and have the following select:

```
<select id="selectYear" name="selectYear" dojoType="ComboBox" style="width:200px;font-size:16px;" >
</select>
```

I am attempting to handle the change event:

```
var select = dom.byId("selectYear");
on(select, "change", function(e) {
```

..

However, I am getting the following error on this line:

```
on(select, "change", function(e) {
```

The error is:

```
MapView.js:351 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Not sure what the problem is.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Hi Robert.The section where the patient was taken is not descriptive. Because of the error received, the general JavaScript DOM error. It has nothing to do with Esri. For example, if you can prepare an application where you receive an error, a quick solution can be found.

Comment: First, verify if dom.byId("selectYear"); returns a node and not undefined

Comment: add some sample where your are facing similar issue.. that will help us to rectify exact cause to provide u a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a problem on your template and possibly on you code to retrieve the combo widget.

Try changing you template to,

```
<select id="selectYear" name="selectYear" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox"
  style="width:200px;font-size:16px;" >
</select>
```

And to retrieve the combo widget use `dijit\registry` like this,

```
registry.byId("selectYear").on("change", function() {
  ...
});
```